# How to iterate through array inside objects which is inside main object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, iteration, javascript-objects

I have an API: https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

It contains an object, which contains 3 keys (Division) whose value is also an object and it includes an array showing holiday Details (events). I want to print the "title" and 'date' from it for each Division. Below is the code. How to render the data for title and date inside the Holiday.js?

```
     export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetApi = () => {
    fetch("https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((items) => setData(items));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Holidays data={Object.entries(data)} />
    </div>
  );
}

/ / Holiday.js

const Holidays = ({ data }) => {
  // console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <ol>
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <li key= {i}>
              <div>title:</div>    //render title here
               <div>Date :</div>    //render date here
           </li>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is Sandbox link : [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-on-holiday-api-zop9g)

Answer (score 1):

Change Holliday Element into: (explanation on comments)

```
const Holidays = ({ data }) => {
  // console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <ol className="App">
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          // since you are passing Object.entries, the first parameter is the key
          // and the second one are the values
          const [key, obj] = item;

          // you then just have to map the event inside the values
          return obj.events.map((o, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <div>title: {o.title}</div>
              <div>Date : {(o.date)}</div>
            </li>
          ));
        })}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your Holiday comonent with this

```
const Holidays = ({ data }) => {
  const ListItem = (array) => {
    console.log(array);
    return array[1].events.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <li key={i}>
          <div>title: {item.title}</div>
          <div>Date :{item.date}</div>
        </li>
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ol>{data.map((array) => ListItem(array))}</ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Holidays;
```